# Convert a look-behind regex from python to javascript

Tags: javascript, python, regex, lookbehind

I have written a regex pattern with positive look-behind in `python` which matches a comma-separated list of mobile numbers. The pattern is:

```
^\+?[0-9]+((,?)(?(1)(\+?[0-9]+)))*$
```

It matches any mobile number regarding following constraints:

1. Each phone number can start with `+`; any other `+` characters are forbidden.
2. Each phone number can start with `00`.
3. Spaces are not acceptable; not middle spaces nor peripherals.

My pattern works fine in `python`, but I want to convert it to `javascript` version in order to use it in an `angular` project.

I googled about *javascript look-behind regex*, but I couldn't figure out how to make use of indexed look-behind in `javascript`; the `?(1)` part.

Is there any way to convert this `python` regex to `javascript` or any other equivalent regex to match my needs?

Comment: There is no lookbebhind in the pattern, there is a conditional construct here, and I doubt it works as expected since your group 1 is `((,?)(?(1)(\+?[0-9]+)))`. I think what you were after is a plain [`^\+?[0-9]+(?:,\+?[0-9]+)*$`](https://regex101.com/r/NzStiy/1) pattern.

Comment: I’m not sure I understand the use of the conditional here. It looks to me like you could add the yes clause directly after the comma.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Given that your regex doesn’t seem to use lookbehinds or the no-clause of the conditional, I believe this should do it:

```
^\+?[0-9]+(,\+?[0-9]+)*$
```

Comment: Why do you think it should do?

Comment: Because it matches numbers following the constraints in the question. Have I missed something?

Comment: Still wondering what the issue is. :-S

Comment: Your pattern worked for all my cases.